# How to make Notification Silent using RingtoneManager

Tags: java, android, uri, android-preferences, ringtonemanager

I have added a checkbox preference in `preferences.xml`. There is a `settings.java` file which has defined all the preferences. 
Now There is a seperate java file which displays a notification when a message comes in. 
If the checkbox is true, I would like to make the notification silent.

```
    if(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Receiver.mContext).getString(Settings.PREF_SILENT_MODE, "").equals("true"))
                            //Make the notification silent ie. 
    else
           Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

notification.sound = alarmSound;
```

There is a `TYPE_NOTIFICATION` method associated with Ringtone manager for notification type of sound. Is there a way to make this silent?

I know there is a way to make it silent using AudioManager.  `setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);`
But here, ringtone manager is being used.

Edit--**FIGURED IT OUT**
(flag is a boolean value which returned the checkbox preference result from SharedPreferences)

`settings.java` file-

```
public boolean checksilentmode(Context mContext)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        return prefs.getBoolean(PREF_SILENT_MODE,DEFAULT_SILENT_MODE);
    }
```

Another java file-

```
   `if(flag)  //if flag is true ie silent mode is enabled.      
     {    
        alarmSound=null;
     }
    else 
    {

alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }

        notification.sound = alarmSound;`
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do all of this ...if you are showing notification using NotificationCompact.Builder do something like below

```
notificatiomCompactBuilder.setDefaults(4);
```